# Rails 2 -- Load Gems based on the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Like rails 3, do we have a functionality of loading specific gems according to the application environment.

[rails 3 example](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/)

```
group :production do
  gem "activemerchant"
end
```

do we have anything similar to the above code in rails2

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the gems in the appropriate environment files.

So instead of having them all defined in `environment.rb`, define the ones you want in `development.rb` and `production.rb` etc.

```
# development.rb
config.gem 'sqlite3'

# production.rb
config.gem 'mysql'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use different files for different environments then you can use:

```
if Rails.env.production?
   config.gem 'activemerchant'
end
```

Comment: Rails already has these different files, might as well use them. Also, `RAILS_ENV` is deprecated, `Rails.env` is the replacement.

Comment: In fact `Rails.env` returns a `StringInquirer`, so you can do `if Rails.env.production? ...`.

Comment: @Douglas - I thought that RAILS_ENV is deprecated since Rails 3 but it is since 2... I have updated my answer, thank you :)